# How to pass a jFrame with jTable via sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, jtable, client-server, jframe

I have a client-server application, in the client side i have a button to recieve a frame
with table inside it from the server.
If i pass the frame with other jComponents (JButton,JTextField) it works fine, but when i'm
tryin to pass the frame with a jTable i'm getting null exception in the client side.

Here is my code:

Client side:

```
private class GetServerData extends Thread
{
    String server_msg = " ";
    Socket the_client;
    ObjectInputStream from_server;

    public GetServerData(Socket client)
    {
        the_client = client;
        try {
            from_server = new ObjectInputStream(the_client.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        do {
            try {
                Object obj = from_server.readObject(); // this is the line when the exception reference to 
                                                       // when trying to read the JFRAME 
                if (obj instanceof JFrame) {
                    JFrame window = (JFrame)obj;
                    window.setVisible(true);
                    window.pack();
                }
                else {
                    server_msg = (String)obj;
                    System.out.println(server_msg);
                }
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while(!server_msg.equals("bye"));
    }
}
```

Server Side:

```
public void run(){
    while (true){
        try {
            data_from_client = (Vector)from_client.readObject();
            if (data_from_client.elementAt(0)equals("string")) {
                String s = "Hello user";
                to_client.writeObject(s);
                to_client.flush();
            }                   
            else if (data_from_client.elementAt(0).equals("table")) {
                String [][]d = {{"yoyo","jojo"},{"koko","momo"}}; 
                String []h   = {"name","best friend"};
                JTable jtable = new JTable(d,h);
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jtable);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Im from the server!!");
                frame.add(panel);
                to_client.writeObject(frame);
                to_client.flush();
            }
            //else if (data_from_client.elementAt(0).equals("bye")) {
            //    to_client.println("bye");
            //    to_client.flush();
            //    socket.close();
            //    socket = null;
            //}
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException ioe) {
            break;
            // error in reading streams from client
        }
    }
    close();
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-21" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at pack.connect_to_server.ServerConnection$GetServerData.run(ServerConnection.java:92)
```

I've commented in the client side, where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing JFrames (or any Window for that matter) via `Serialization` is a bad idea, in my experience, this seems to come down to the connection it has to the systems native peer, once transferred, this is lost and generally causes lots of nasty problems, in my experience.

I could be missing really obvious and some has over come these limitations, but I've not found away.

If you can, you should only transfer the data content instead, it's generally safer and a lot less messy ;)

Comment: There is not much good and a lot bad with sending GUI objects to a server.  As MadProgrammer said, you should send DATA and to and from the server and leave the GUI side to a GUI program.

Comment: thanks guys...
so instead of sending jframe itself, is it good idea to save it in 
xml file, and send the file to the client.. and in the client side 
to populate the data and after that build the frame?

Comment: @eliorsh That's a slightly better idea, personally, I'd only package the data you want to replicate on the client and leave out the rest

Comment: ok thank you!
i also read in other thread, that someone recommend to add 
all the data (like jbutton,jtextfield) to jpanel and send
the jpanel to the client.. what do you say about it?

here is the thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567033/serializing-a-jframe-and-sending-via-network

Comment: The problem is you could encounter random problems associated with the various sub elements related to the UI. Generally, you'll have less problems by sending just the data, but it's your choice